# How to match '|' with searchpair

Tags: vim

I have some ruby code that goes like

```
some_hash = {
  hello: world,
  goodbye: moon
}
some_hash.each do |key, value|
  # process
end
```

I want to know how to get `searchpair` to work to match the '|' character. Every time I execute `echo searchpair('|', '', '|', 'W')` inside the '|' characters, vim returns `0`.

Comment: [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10219/4729) has a hint: apparently `searchpair` doesn't work when `start` and `end` are equal. It's not about `|` specifically.  The answer suggests using `search` twice, as a workaround.

Comment: @Amadan  thank you for your response. I appreciate the response. I will try to create a solution using  `search`. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

As @Amadan said, `searchpair` does not work when `start` and `end` are equal. The main goal of this was to create operator-pending mappings to match between and around two `|`. I ended up creating a generic solution that allows me to match on equal patterns on the same line. You can find the code [here](https://gist.github.com/raman162/149345ae335525505ced0bd291d68623).